# How to place messagebox.showerror on top of all Toplevels?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm building a tkinter application in which several Toplevels might be open at any one time. If a user provides invalid input when performing a new calculation, possibly unrelated to those that led to other open Toplevels, I need for a `messagebox.showerror` to appear without closing any of the open Toplevels.

The problem I'm encountering is that the messagebox appears on top of the root but is obscured by the open Toplevels. The pseudocode snippet below appears at the start of a function that performs the desired calculation:

```
if input is invalid:
    messagebox.showerror('Error','Your input is invalid!')
    return
```

It would be simple to close the Toplevels before showing the error message, but I'd strongly prefer they stay open while the user corrects their error.

Is there an option for `messagebox.showerror` that will accomplish what I desire? (I can't locate one.) Is it possible to place my messagebox inside a new Toplevel that appears on top of all others? Or must I resort to creating a button manually with a new callback that serves the purpose of the `return` above?

Comment: what about to set the latest Toplevel as parent of messagebox() ?

Comment: Why not make your own error screen from scratch? All you need if a sprite for the error icon and a bit of code for the label+close button. After that you can make sure that that `Toplevel` is shown above everything else. I did that once and it didn't take me a lot of time. I would post my code but I made quite a few alterations.

Comment: @Bohdan: That would seem logical to me, i.e. `messagebox.showerror('Error','Your input is invalid!',parent=Toplevel)` but I get no error box at all.

 @ThinLizzard: Making my own error screen from scratch is likely what I'll have to do. 

Thanks much.

Comment: Also if you are feeling nice today, post the code as an answer for other people to see